# Setting width of bars (linear and log)

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I have two sets of data that I want to compare by displaying it in plotly.
With the basic setting I get incredibly thin lines that are not making any sense to read, so I tried to set up the width-parameter.

The result is kind of weird. I tried to use just `width=1`, but only the first bars were affected. So I set it for all the values and the result just gets weirder.

```
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = df_orig["Records"].drop_duplicates().values.tolist(),
                         y = df_orig.groupby("Records")["File Size"].sum(),
                         offset = 0.0005,
                         width = [1.5] * len(df_orig["Records"].drop_duplicates()),
                         name = 'Original',
                         text= df['File Size']))

    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = df_compr["Records"].drop_duplicates().values.tolist(),
                         y = df_compr.groupby("Records")["File Size"].sum(),
                         width = 10,
                         name = 'Compressed',
                         text= df['File Size']))
```

This code does essentially what it should (I think, I can't properly read the values on the plot). However I can't make sense of how to set the width of the bars:

[image]

When changing to the Logarithmic Plot the bars are behaving very differently.
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is there an explanation for this behavior?

Edit:

How I do the log axis:

```
fig.update_layout(self.getLayout())#Right after the aforementioned code
```

And the method

```
@classmethod
def getLayout(cls,title="Linear scale"):
    return dict(updatemenus=cls.getUpdateMenu(), title=title)

@staticmethod
def getUpdateMenu():
    return list([
        dict(active=1,
             buttons=list([dict(label='Log Scale',
                                method='update',
                                args=[{'visible': [True, True]},
                                      {'title': 'Log scale',
                                       'xaxis': {'type': 'log'},
                                       'yaxis': {'type': 'log'}
                                      }]),
                           dict(label='Linear Scale',
                                method='update',
                                args=[{'visible': [True, False]},
                                      {'title': 'Linear scale',
                                       'xaxis': {'type': 'linear'},
                                       'yaxis': {'type': 'linear'}}])
             ]),
        )
    ])
```

Comment: Is the x-axis in log format? Try to deactivate it and does it change? And width=1 is the maximum value, so you need to set it below 1.0.

Comment: @r-beginners both is log. For good reasons. I set it to 1 before and kept playing.

Comment: I am sure that there are multiple tiny lines in each visible line in the first plot. Thus, when you use the logarithmic transformation, you get multiple thick lines merged together.

Comment: @Hamzah - the overlapping lines are not the problem, that is intended. The issue is that when a logarithmic x-axis is used the bars behave logarithmic also

Comment: What do you mean by bars behave logarithmic?

Comment: @Hamzah - check out the width of the bars in the last picture. They get smaller the further they are from 0

Comment: Could you please share the code of the logarithmic transformation you used?